# Searching keywords using spotlight?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, spotlight

I have a list of keywords that I want to search through out all my employee's iPad's, is it possible to call spotlight and get the results programmatically?

Thank you.

Edit:
Basically an app that would search for custom keywords on all other apps on the iPad and return the results on a simple list. 
I'm guessing my best bet is through the use of spotlight, but I was hoping I could programmatically call the spotlight engine to make the search for me, and get the results.

Comment: what do you mean with "I want to search through out all my employee's iPad's". can you provide an example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write an app is able to access (much less search) the data of other apps running iOS.

That's the magic of app sandboxing ([detailed in this "iOS Environment" Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html)).